# When i send my form, my checkboxes values results always NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

i have a form where i populate some checkboxes from the table HairTags ,

all works fine, i show my checkboxes in my form, but when i choose some of them and i try to send, all the value results NULL and i do not save them ids inside my filed Creationtag

in my model

```
//CHECKBOXES
public class HairTagModel
{
    //[Key]
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}



public class CreationHairTagsModel
{
    //public Creation Creation { get; set; }
    //public List<HairTagModel> CreationHairTags { get; set; }

    public CreationHairTagsModel()
    {
        Creation = new Creation();
    }
    public Creation Creation { get; set; }

    private ApplicationDbContext creationdb = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public List<HairTagModel> CreationHairTags
    {
        get
        { 
            var HairTagList = creationdb.HairTags.ToList();

            List<HairTagModel> obj = new List<HairTagModel>();

            foreach (var tags in HairTagList)
            {
                obj.Add(new HairTagModel
                {
                    Text = tags.HairTagTitle,
                    Value = tags.HairTagId,
                    IsChecked = false
                });
            }

            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

in my page

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CreationHairTags.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.CreationHairTags[i].IsChecked)
        @Model.CreationHairTags[i].Text
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CreationHairTags[i].Value)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CreationHairTags[i].Text)<br />
    }
</div>
```

in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreationUpload(CreationHairTagsModel creationbind, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {   
    ///...CODE HIDDEN...

       //Tags
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in creationbind.CreationHairTags)
        {
            if (item.IsChecked)
            {                                        
                sb.Append(item.Value + ",");
            }
        }
        creationbind.Creation.Creationtag = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

What is wrong in my code please help and explain ?

Comment: Hi, i took them off, but i got the same problem.

Comment: You property needs to be `public List<HairTagModel> CreationHairTags { get; set; }`. Your view models should never have database access code (its impossible to unit test). Its the controller which is responsible for access the database (and in this case, set the value of `CreationHairTags`

Comment: In the controller GET method - `var model = new CreationHairTagsModel(); model.CreationHairTags = creationdb.HairTags.Select(x => new HairTagModel { Text = x.HairTagTitle, Value = x.HairTagId }).ToList(); return View(model);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Model doesn't provide a method a setter for the List.  Just a getter.

Essentially you have made that field readonly.  I won't go into the violations of SOLID that this code has. You could get the data back from the modelbinder a different way, try

```
public ActionResult CreationUpload(CreationHairTagsModel creationbind, List<HairTagModel> creationHairTags, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

The model binder should populate the creationHairTags parameter with the values it finds in the form list.

Comment: Hi thanks @Slicksim, i replaced with your code in my controller, and i also did here : foreach (var item in creationHairTags) and now is working!! sorry, i am a beginner with MVC and i don't know what "violations of SOLID" is.

Comment: @CarlesAmnesty, The answer is correct as far as the missing setter, but do not change your POST method (adding the `List<HairTagModel> creationHairTags` parameter would never work)

Comment: Do not do it (your not understanding the model binding process). See my comment in your question.

Comment: Hi @Stephen Muecke, but if i take off this code : my checked checkboxes are no longer taken.. and all values are not checked = NULL.. sorry but i lost something... what should i do in stead? (But... how comes that this code works?)

Comment: @CarlesAmnesty. Did you change the property to `public List<HairTagModel> CreationHairTags { get; set; }`?

Comment: Hi @Stephen Muecke, i am a bit confused... in my model i have this : public List<HairTagModel> CreationHairTags      {       get      {      var HairTagList = creationdb.HairTags.ToList();      List<HairTagModel> obj = new List<HairTagModel>();      foreach (var tags in HairTagList)       {      obj.Add(new HairTagModel       {      Text = tags.HairTagTitle,      Value = tags.HairTagId,      IsChecked = false      });      }      return obj;      }      } As you can see above.. Do you mean i need to change something in my model? What about?

Comment: Read my comment in your question and my previous comment in this answer. NEVER have database access code in your view model. You property needs to be a simple `{get; set; } and in the controller, you call the database and set its value.

Comment: Hi @Stephen Muecke, ok now i understand.. than i should take of the database access from my model and populate it in my controller.. I am sorry to bother you with this, but i am a beginner, would you that kind to write an answer with the example code to use in my controller? Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: @CarlesAmnesty, I have added a comment in your question, but you should accept this answer because it correctly points out that your missing a `setter` (meaning that the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** the value of your property.

Comment: Hi @Stephen Muecke, amazing!! i chaged with your code and all works fine!!! thanks again.. another thing... now for my EDIT part in my controller, how can implement my code? : // GET: /Creation/CreationEdit/5            [Authorize]           public ActionResult CreationEdit(int? id)           {            Creation creation = db.Creations.Find(id);            return View(creation);            }

Comment: Sorry, but you need to ask a new question (that'show this site works)

Comment: Hi @Stephen Muecke, i have opend another discussion, here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354989/generated-checkboxes-how-to-make-working-my-code-with-my-edit-part-in-my-contr